# CAKEPHP self referencing table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a self reference table defined thus:-

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'ChildCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_category_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'ParentCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_category_id',
        'conditions' => array('ParentCategory.parent_category_id' => '0'),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

We only have one level of parent child so a tree is alittle ott. I'm trying to code the find to get a list of parents only for the add edit functions.

```
    $parentCategories = $this->Category->ParentCategory->find('list');
```

However the sql does not contain my condition???

SELECT `ParentCategory`.`id`, `ParentCategory`.`name` FROM `bidup`.`categories` AS `ParentCategory` WHERE 1 = 1

Is there a reason that the condition is not being included?

Comment: I'm not too familiar on conditions on the model relationships, but it could be that it only applies to the join.  You could get what you want by doing `$parentCategories = $this->Category->ParentCategory->find('list', 'conditions' => array('parent_category_id' => 0));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions on the `$belongsTo` relationship will only apply when retrieving the ParentCategory from a query on Category (assuming the relationships you show are just in the Category model).

This means if you did a `find()` on Category and included ParentCategory through either the `recursive` or `contain` parameters, or maybe used `read()` then that condition would be used.

When you query directly on ParentCategory that condition in the model is by-passed, you're just using that relationship as a short-cut to getting to that model without having to load it directly or put it in your `$uses`.

As user2076809 suggested, if you specifically want to use list on ParentCategory then your best option is likely to include the condition yourself:

```
$parentCategories = $this->Category->ParentCategory->find(
  'list',
  array(
    'conditions' => array('ParentCategory.parent_category_id' => 0),
  )
);
```